# Store data structure c++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have alot of data (7k lines) stored in this way:

```
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
std::deque<std::deque<std::vector<unsigned char>>> data =
{
  {{0}},
  {{1,0},
   {0,1}},
  {{1,1,0,0},
   {0,1,1,0},
   {1,0,0,1},
   {0,1,0,1},
   {0,0,1,1}},
  {{1,1,1,0,0,0},
   {0,1,1,1,0,0},
   {1,0,1,0,1,0},
   {0,1,1,0,1,0},
   ...
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}}
};
```

This makes my code run much faster since I can skip some parts. The length of the vectors does not need to be variable, but this was just a simple way.
The problem is that it now takes in the matter of minutes, instead of seconds to compile.

Is there a better way to store this data? Or should it be loaded at run time?

If it is loaded at run time, won't it just take time there?

Comment: What kind of data is this?

Comment: @DonReba: What you mean by instant? Of course 7k lines of data (which maybe need some parsing) will take time at runtime.

Comment: @Nidhoegger, micro or milliseconds compared to minutes.

Comment: The program also has to be read from the disk. This means that loading the data takes time *no matter what*. The question is how long.

Comment: @DonReba Patent nonsense. Loading several thousand values at runtime isn't magically cost-free. Also, sacrificing runtime speed for compile time is silly.

Comment: I would also do it at compile time...

Comment: Why is speed so critical to you? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Olipro, as Jorgen remarked, the data will have to be read from disk no matter what. The difference is that you won't need to compile it as C++ code.

Comment: @DonReba and that's great if the only person using the code is you and you compile it as frequently as you run it. Some bold assumptions you have there.

Comment: @Olipro, I don't get your statement. The more people are using the code, the more benefit from leaving data in an external file. There is no benefit at all in having it in source code.

Comment: @DonReba more bold assumptions. How do you know it's better off in an external file? If the data never changes and/or you don't *want* the user to modify it, that's clearly false. never mind the issue of actually serializing and unserializing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start by thinking about what you are trying to achieve. Are you afraid that your program will feel sluggish to the user?

Loading 7kB of data from a hard drive will be faster than any human will be able to notice. My guess is that it would be fine for almost any purpose.
If the data can be compiled in, it must be constant, which means that it will only ever have to be loaded once anyway. Even safety critical systems with hard deadlines can usually afford a few milliseconds during program initialization.

In the unlikely case that this even matters, you should measure the time
it takes to load the data and see if it is acceptable for your purpose.

Comment: Besides, the data will be loaded from hard drive in any case, whether it is part of the compiled binary or a separate file.

Comment: @Don Reba: Exactly. It will probably be a tiny bit faster though, since the data can be loaded in a single pass.

Answer (score 4):

Look into whether or not your compiler supports a pre-compiled header and if so, make this data part of that PCH. This will result in the slow work only occuring when the data actually changes and will separate it out from all your other code changes.

If, for some reason a PCH isn't an option, you could also create a header that `extern`'s your `std::vector` and have a single .cpp file containing your ~7k lines of elements. Most compilers won't recompile a single unit if the file is unmodified.

Comment: Backing this! PCHs are great for this!

Comment: That's not enough detail to diagnose: Just because you generate a precompiled header doesn't mean it's necessarily using it everywhere else that you include it. A good indicator it's not actually working would be that not only is the PCH generation really slow, but everything else is too.